# Add all elements of an iterable to list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Is there a more concise way of doing the following?

```
t = (1,2,3)
t2 = (4,5)

l.addAll(t)
l.addAll(t2)
print l # [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This is what I have tried so far: I would prefer to avoid passing in the list in the parameters.

```
def t_add(t,stuff):
    for x in t:
        stuff.append(x)
```

Comment: Presumably you want any existing pre-elements in `l` to be still there if `l` wasn't empty, right?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use `list.extend()`, not `list.append()` to add all items from an iterable to a list:

```
l.extend(t)
l.extend(t2)
```

or

```
l.extend(t + t2)
```

or even:

```
l += t + t2
```

where `list.__iadd__` (in-place add) is implemented as `list.extend()` under the hood.

Demo:

```
>>> l = []
>>> t = (1,2,3)
>>> t2 = (4,5)
>>> l += t + t2
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If, however, you just wanted to create a list of `t + t2`, then `list(t + t2)` would be the shortest path to get there.

Comment: I'm newer to Python, so this may be a naive question, but how did you know that this works for arbitrary iterables, and not just lists?  [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) says (emphasis added) "*list.extend(L)
Extend the list by appending all the items in the **given list**. Equivalent to `a[len(a):] = L`.*"  This might be documented, but I'm not sure where... I see [Views And Iterators Instead Of Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), but that's more a "what's changed?" entry.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: It looks like the documentation in Python 3 was updated. Now it says: "list.extend(iterable) Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable. Equivalent to a[len(a):] = iterable.". As for Python 2, I tried "help([].extend)" and also got: "L.extend(iterable) -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable". The respective documentation [link](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html) looks to be not completely correct.

Answer (score 13):

`stuff.extend` is what you want.

```
t = [1,2,3]
t2 = [4,5]
t.extend(t2)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or you can do

```
t += t2
```

Comment: no sir, we don't want to mutate the original list

Comment: @TSR Who is "we"? The question does want to.

Answer (score 0):

## performance comparison: `list.extend()` is the best

```
In [1]: it1 = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: it2 = (4, 5)

In [3]: %timeit -n 1000000 it1 + list(it2)
146 ns ± 0.475 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit -n 1000000 it1 + [el for el in it2]
221 ns ± 0.368 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [5]: import itertools

In [6]: %timeit -n 1000000 list(itertools.chain(it1, it2))
352 ns ± 1.19 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit -n 1000000 it1.copy().extend(it2)
123 ns ± 1.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit -n 1000000 it1.extend(it2)  # WARNING: this modifies it1
51.5 ns ± 0.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: You forgot `it1 += it2`.